# subprocess.Popen with shell=True hangs on 'time <...>'

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I'm using this code, which is supposed to be transitional for python2 to python3 porting phase (I know there are third-party libs for `run`, I want to implement my own to collect experience)

```
def run(args,
        stdin=None, input=None,
        stdout=None, stderr=None, capture_output=False,
        timeout=None,
        encoding=None,
        **popen_kwargs):        
    # create stderr and stdout pipes, if capture_output is true
    if capture_output:
        _stderr = subprocess.PIPE
        _stdout = subprocess.PIPE
    else:
        _stdout, _stderr = stdout, stderr

    # if input is given, create stdin as pipe, where input will be passed into
    if input is not None:
        _stdin = subprocess.PIPE
    else:
        _stdin = stdin

    # this starts the process. python2 did not have 'encoding'
    if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=_stdin, stdout=_stdout, stderr=_stderr, encoding=encoding,
                                **popen_kwargs)
    else:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            args, stdin=_stdin, stdout=_stdout, stderr=_stderr, **popen_kwargs)

    # run a background timer to interrupt 'communicate', if necessary
    if timeout is not None:
        def cancel():
            try:
                proc.terminate()
            except OSError:
                # an exception here means that the process is gone already
                pass
        cancel_timer = Timer(timeout, cancel)
        cancel_timer.start()

    # special case for python2 for which we allow passing 'unicode' if an encoding is used
    if input is not None and sys.version_info.major < 3:
        if type(input) == unicode:
            import codecs
            input = codecs.encode(input, encoding)
    (stdoutoutput, stderroutput) = proc.communicate(input)

    # check timeout scenario
    if timeout is not None:
        if not cancel_timer.is_alive():
            raise TimeoutExpired(args, timeout, stdoutoutput,
                                 stdoutoutput, stderroutput)
        else:
            cancel_timer.cancel()
            cancel_timer.join()

    # on python2, outputs will always be 'str', which is fine with us, as it's the union of
    # str and bytes
    return CompletedProcess(args, proc.poll(), stdoutoutput, stderroutput)
```

However, the code blocks indefinitely within `communicate` whenever I try to execute anything with the shell builtin `time` prefixed and `capture_output` on both python2 and python3. It must be something really stupid.

```
>>> run("time sleep 5m", shell=True, capture_output=True, timeout=1)
... (^ C to stop it)
>>> run("sleep 5m", shell=True, capture_output=True, timeout=1)
zsubprocess.TimeoutExpired: sleep 5m: Timeout after 1 seconds
```

I do not understand why that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, `subprocess` does *not* execute a shell when the command is just `sleep 5m`, but only when it is `time sleep 5m` (more accurately: `sh` optimizes its `-c` and apparently `exec`s it instead of forking).

When I executed `proc.terminate()`, it only terminated the wrapper shell, but not the `sleep`, which became a child of the child subreaper (`init` here). And possibly (I guess) `communicate` wait for the pipes to yield EOF to collect outstanding data, which won't happen unless the sleep terminates. The following solution was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25134985/34509 . Instead of `proc.kill`, do

```
process = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
if proc.poll() is None:
    for child in process.children(recursive=True):
        child.kill()
    process.kill()
```

There's a small chance that we could race with the process, where it could create new processes before we could kill them, but at least simple cases work now!